# Azure Template spec caching

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-rm-template

I have a Azure template spec, version "ado", which has been working great. I recently changed a parameter name (ie. "location" to "aslocation") and updated the template spec using Powershell's Set-AzTemplateSpec command with the same version name "ado"

But when I call the template spec using the new parameter name, "aslocation", it throws:

```
Error BCP037: The property "aslocation" is not allowed on objects of type "params". Permissible properties include "location"
```

Even if I try using the old parameter name, "location", it throws:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. D:\git\IaC\Azure\main.bicep(4,5) : Error BCP035: The specified "object" declaration is missing the following required properties: "location". D:\git\IaC\Azure\main.bicep(5,7) : Error BCP089: The property "aslocation" is not allowed on objects of type "params". Did you mean "location"?
```

So it seems something is being cached. Any ideas on how to resolve or avoid this problem?

I have confirmed:

- Occurs using Azure CLI or Powershell commands
- Occurs using VS Code's integrated terminal or standalone powershell/CMD terminals
- Template spec is indeed updated (verified via portal)
- Issue persists through multiple days/reboots

Comment: Can you share the code in main.bicep?  And the commands you're using to deploy?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue. Leaving this here in case anyone else runs into this problem.

Bicep maintains a local cache for template specs at %USERPROFILE%.bicep
This is NOT automatically updated when template spec versions are updated. You must use Bicep CLI's restore command with the --force flag to refresh it (or remove your cache).

This seems counterintuitive IMHO but I digress..

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-cli#restore